# Fetching child entities in Mysql/Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

I use JPA as persistence engine to handle database queries. The tables (MySQL) are as follows:

```
Parent - table
+-----+---------+
|id   |   name  |
+-----+---------+
| 1   |  name1  |
| 2   |  name2  |
| 3   |  name3  |
+---------------+

child1 - table 
+--+---------+------+
|id|parent_id|name  |
+--+---------+------+
| 1|   1     |  qwe |
| 2|   1     |  asd | 
| 3|   1     |  dsf |
| 4|   2     |  xzc |
+--+---------+------+

child2 - table 
+--+---------+------+------+
|id|parent_id|type  |name  |
+--+---------+------+------+
| 1|   1     |  1   | qqq  |
| 2|   1     |  1   | www  |
| 3|   1     |  1   | eee  |
| 4|   1     |  2   | aaa  |
| 5|   1     |  2   | sss  |
| 6|   1     |  2   | ddd  |
| 7|   1     |  3   | zzz  |
| 8|   2     |  1   | xxx  |
+--+---------+------+------+
```

And my classes are

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Child1> children1;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Child2> children2;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child1")
public class Child1{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false)
    private Parent parent;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child2")
public class Child2{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private int type;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false)
    private Parent parent;

}
```

I would like to get Parents and child entities (embedded their own **List** objects in **Parent** java object) in the following manner. I just want to get child1 entities with **maximum** id for each parent.

(for the given example, child1(id:3) for parent(id:1) and child1(id:4) for parent(id:2)).

Also I want to get child2 with **maximum** id for each **type** of child2.

(for the given example, child2(id:3)(max of type:1), child2(id:6)(max of type:2), child2(id:7)(max of type:3) for parent(id:1) and child2(id:8)(max of type:1) for parent(id:2))

At last, Parent(id:1) has one Child1(id:3) in List children1 and has three Child2(id:3, id:6, id:7) in List children2.

Sorry for my poor English.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you want the Child1 object with max id for a parent you do a JPQL Query. So what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You should really post what you have tried so far, but since I can't Comment Everywhere™ yet, I will help you with the first one and you can try the second on your own.

I am assuming you are asking for the HQL to perform your query. Try this:

```
select max(c.id), c.parent.id from Child1 c group by child1.parent.id
```

The second query you wanted is very similar, if you can get that one to work then it should be easy.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What i want to get is the parent entities and filtered childs within. I cannot combine those two queries.

Comment: So instead of returning a parent entity with all its children, you want it to return only the children that meet your requirements? I think that using something like the filters mentioned (as long as you don't need to possibility change to another implementation of JPA).

Comment: No, I need the parents. Because I would like to get a number of parents and list it in my client side application with their filtered children.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to filter on the child collection. Look into [Hibernate Filters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html)

Comment: why would you do that? why advise someone to throw away JPA vendor independence with no reason?

Comment: Isn't the question for fetching the Parent entitiy with the filtered child list? even if u write a JPQL query on parent, wont it fetch the parent with all the child rows ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely i try to get the parent with filtered child list. But i cannot write the query; that is what i need.

Comment: I try to use filter but i could not find any way to get the child with max id or get the children with max id for each type.